# Kafka Producer design - multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to implement a Kafka producer/consumer model, and am deliberating whether creating a separate publisher thread per topic would be preferred over having a single publisher handle multiple topics. Any help would be appreciated

PS: I'm new to Kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *separate publisher thread*, I think you mean *separate producer objects*. If so..

Since messages are stored as key-value pairs in Kafka, different topics *can* have different key-value types.
So if your Kafka topics have different key-value types like for example..

```
Topic1 - key:String, value:Student
Topic2 - key:Long, value:Teacher
```

and so on, then you should be using multiple producers. This is because the `KafkaProducer` class at the time of constructing the object asks you for the key and value serializers.

```
Properties props=new Properties();
props.put("key.serializer",StringSerializer.class);
props.put("value.serializer",LongSerializer.class);
KafkaProducer<String,Long> producer=new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

*Though, you may also write a generic serializer for all the types!* But, it is better to know before hand what we are doing with the producer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Keep It Stupid Simple [(KISS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) approach for the sake of obvious reasons - one producer / multiple producers - one topic.

From Wikipedia,

> The KISS principle states that most systems work best if they are kept simple rather than made complicated; therefore, simplicity should be a key goal in design, and unnecessary complexity should be avoided.

Talking about the possibility of one producer supporting multiple topics, it is also far from the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 2.5, you can use a RoutingKafkaTemplate to select the producer at runtime, based on the destination topic name.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#routing-template
Single Publisher can handle multiple Topics and you can customize the Producer Config as per Topic needs

Answer (score -1):

I think a separate thread for each topic would be preferred because due to some reasons if the particular producer is down then the respected topic will be impacted and remaining all the topics will work smoothly without any problem.

If we create one publisher for all topics then, if the publisher is down for some reasons then all the topics would impact.